# Python numpy nan compare to true in arrays with strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to compare two numpy arrays which contain numbers, string and nans. I want to know how many items in the array are equal.

When comparing these two arrays:

```
c =np.array([1,np.nan]);
d =np.array([2,np.nan]);
print (c==d)
[False False]
```

Which is the expected behaviour.

However, when comparing:

```
a =np.array([1,'x', np.nan]);
b =np.array([1,'x', np.nan]);
print (a==b)
[ True  True  True]
```

That makes no sense to me, how can adding a string to the array change the way nans are compared? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the arrays, you'll see that `np.nan` has been converted to string (`'n'`):

```
In [48]: a = np.array([1, 'x', np.nan])

In [49]: a
Out[49]: 
array(['1', 'x', 'n'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

And `'n' == 'n'` is `True`.

What I don't understand is why changing the array's `dtype` to `object` doesn't change the result of the comparison:

```
In [72]: a = np.array([1, 'x', np.nan], dtype=object)

In [73]: b = np.array([1, 'x', np.nan], dtype=object)

In [74]: a == b
Out[74]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [75]: a[2] == b[2]
Out[75]: False

In [76]: type(a[2])
Out[76]: float

In [77]: type(b[2])
Out[77]: float
```

It's almost as if the two NaN objects are compared by reference rather than by value:

```
In [79]: id(a[2])
Out[79]: 26438340

In [80]: id(b[2])
Out[80]: 26438340
```

Comment: In numpy 1.9.1 when comparing your `a` and `b` I get "FutureWarning: numpy equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.". Looks like this is a known issue (feature?).

Comment: Well, comparing `NaN` as an object, I except it to be equal. NaN as a float should be always False. But don't now the Numpy-internal very well.

Comment: @sebix: I am afraid I don't understand the distinction you're making, given that `float` is a subclass of `object` (try `isinstance(float, object)`).

Comment: I assume that with object-arrays, Numpy won't use the objects methods to compare, but the ids like you assume.

Comment: @sebix: I can demonstrate that this is not the case: an array with `dtype` of `object` containing strings uses string contents -- and not just ids -- to establish equality.

Comment: But when a string has a different content, the id is also different? Why is this a counterexample?

Comment: @sebix: Try two different strings with identical contents but different ids. `ndarray(dtype=object)` will work correctly, i.e. comparing the contents.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html - `np.nan == np.nan  # is always False!`

Comment: @hpaulj: I don't think there's any confusion about that. What is unclear is why the NaNs compare `True` in the second case (`dtype=object`).

Comment: It must be using the generic `object` comparison rules (`is`) in the one case, and `np.float` rules in the other.